# Typescript: how to find matching properties between 2 objects

Tags: typescript, search, properties

I have 2 objects that have nested properties like this:

```
const obj1 = {
   prop1: {
     val1: 10,
     val2: 11,
     val3: 12,
   },
   prop2: {
     val1: 10,
     diff1: true,
   },
   prop4: {
     text1: 't1',
     text99: 't1',
   }
};
const obj2 = {
   prop1: {
     val99: 1000,
     val2: 1100,
     val33: 1200,
   },
   anotherOne: {
     val1: 1000,
     diff1: false,
   },
   prop4: {
     check: true,
     text1: 't100',
     text99: 't100',
   }
};
```

How can I find which properties are common between both objects?  ie for the above example, I'm interested in getting the following back:

```
const propertiesInObj1AndObj2 = {
   prop1: {
     val2: '',
   },
   prop4: {
     text1: '',
     text99: '',
   }
};
```

Is there a nice way to get this result?  Or do I need to iterate manually over each property found in obj1 and search for the same property in obj2 to see if there is a match?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this really depends on your use cases... do you need to support arrays?  what if both properties exist but are different types?  etc etc etc.

You will have to iterate through the keys of at least one of the objects, but since you are only interested in the intersection of the key sets, you don't need to iterate though both.  The function has to be recursive, of course.

Here's one possible implementation which also works on the type level:

```
type SameKeyThing<T, U> =
    [T, U] extends [object, object] ?
    { [K in (keyof T) & (keyof U)]: SameKeyThing<T[K], U[K]> } : "";

function sameKeyThing<T, U, S=SameKeyThing<T, U>>(x: T, y: U): { [K in keyof S]: S[K] };
function sameKeyThing(x: any, y: any) {
    if ((typeof x !== "object") || (typeof y !== "object")) return "";
    const ret: any = {};
    for (let k in x) {
        if (k in y) {
            ret[k] = sameKeyThing(x[k], y[k]);
        }
    }
    return ret;
}
const propertiesInObj1AndObj2 = sameKeyThing(obj1, obj2);
// inferred as type { prop1: { val2: ""; }; prop4: { text1: ""; text99: ""; }; }
console.log(propertiesInObj1AndObj2);
```

This works well for your example, but probably has weird behavior if you throw edge cases at it (like those arrays).  Anyway, hope this gives you some ideas.  Good luck!

Comment: thanks, I'll give the code a try and tweak it as I need

Answer (score 1):

## O(n2)

> working example https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-2uminr

```
const obj1 = {
   prop1: {
     val1: 10,
     val2: 11,
     val3: 12,
   },
   prop2: {
     val1: 10,
     diff1: true,
   },
   prop4: {
     text1: 't1',
     text99: 't1',
   }
};
const obj2 = {
   prop1: {
     val99: 1000,
     val2: 1100,
     val33: 1200,
   },
   anotherOne: {
     val1: 1000,
     diff1: false,
   },
   prop4: {
     check: true,
     text1: 't100',
     text99: 't100',
   }
};


const duplicate: any[] = [];

Object.keys(obj1).map( ob1 => {
  Object.keys(obj2).map( ob2 => {
    if (match(ob1, ob2)) { duplicate.push(ob2) } 
  });
});

function match(key1: string, key2: string) {
  return (key1 === key2) ? true : false;
}

console.log(duplicate)
```

Comment: this solution doesn't seem to go deeper than the first level of properties.